# Measurable Subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\{E_{j}\}$, $j = 1, 2, ..., \infty$, be measurable subsets of $[0,1]$. Also,

$\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |E_j| = M < \infty$

Let $S_n$ be the set of points in $[0,1]$ contained in at least $n$ of the $E_j$'s. How can we show that that $S_n$ is measurable, with $|S_n| \leq \frac{M}{n}$?

I know that the $E_{j}$'s form a $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets, so $S_n$, as a countable union of some of these measurable $E_{j}$'s is measurable. But I'm not too sure how to derive the M/n upper bound for the measure. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Also, the measure is in terms of Lebesgue measure.

Comment: What are bounds on $\sum |E_j \cap S_n|$?

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the function $f(x)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty 1_{E_j}(x)$.  Think about how you can express $M$ and $S_n$ in terms of $f$.

Comment: Would $f(S_n) \geq n$? I'm not sure how this helps with proving though..

Comment: Also not too sure how $M$ could be expressed as a function of $f$.